# Android: AlarmIntent gets killed when App is force closed on API 23 Lenovo Device - any workaround?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

i have a few AlarmIntents that are registered in the Manifest and therefore can run, even if the App itself not running.

Everything is working fine on my API 26 Emulator, no matter if i clear the TaskManager or not. 
On my 23 real device, the Broadcasts are not working, if the App was force closed via Task Manager.

Is there any workaround for this, or is that just something i have to accept?

Comment: put log in onreceive and check if it prints after device boot

Comment: Hey, i updated my question. I noticed, that the AlarmManager is also not working if i declare it over the Activity, if i destroy the App in the Task Manager afterwards. It works on my Emulator tho.

Comment: if app stops ,then all pending alarm and service will killed.

Comment: Not if the AlarmIntent is registered in the Manifest, which it is. On API 26 it is working, on 23 not..

Comment: did you try another api 23 device?

Comment: Yes, seems to be working on Nexus Emulator with API 23

Comment: which is your device?

Comment: Its a Lenovo Tab3 7Plus, which i have for test purposes.